# regularity of reuleaux triangle

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes

The Reuleaux triangle is the simplest nontrivial example of a curve of constant width - that is, a curve in which all diameters are the same length

my question is what is the regularity of the boundary of reuleaux triangle in $\mathbb{R^2}$

I would like to have answers with references, thank you so much

Comment: Regularity?? The boundary of a Reuleaux triangle is clearly piecewise smooth. In fact, it is simply the union of 3 circular arcs.

Comment: yes , can i said the boundary of reuleaux triangle is$ C^1$ ?

Comment: No, it is $C^{0,1}$, i.e., it is a Lipschitz boundary.

Comment: please can you give me a refrences ?

Comment: Thank you for your responses @gerw could you give me a reference about the regularity of reuleaux triangle ?

Comment: As already said by achille hui, it consists of three circular arcs. Hence, it is Lipschitz and no reference is needed.